# "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition" when trying to upload data to my DB

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, server-error

this is the C# code of the query (*trying to make it so I can upload images to my DB table*):

```
protected void ButtonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        insert();
    }

    public void insert()
    {
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "")
        {
            Byte[] image;
            Stream s = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(s);
            image = br.ReadBytes((Int32)s.Length);

            string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\kfirm\Desktop\KEY_web_v1\KEY_web_v1\App_Data\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            //SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source=.\\sqlexpress; initial catalog=SlideShow; integrated security=true");//ORIGINAL - "data source=.\\sqlexpress; initial catalog=SlideShow; integrated security=true" //I think he's just making a dataset, I can edit later if it doesnt work or add this to the global.asax
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
            comm.Connection = conn;

            comm.CommandText = "INSERT into Portfolio values(@ImageData)"; //I changed stuff!
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageData", image); //I changed stuff!

            conn.Open();
            int row = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            if (row > 0)
            {
                LabelError.Text = "success";
            }

        }
        else LabelError.Text = "please upload an image";
    }
```

this is the HTML code:

```
<form  name="AddSiteToPortfolio" action="AddSiteToPortfolio.aspx" method="post" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ImageData: </td>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonInsert" runat="server" Text="Upload Image" 
    onclick="ButtonInsert_Click" />
            <asp:Label ID="LabelError" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

and this is my tables code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Portfolio] (
[Image]       NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Description] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[ImageData] VARBINARY (max) NULL,
[id]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
);
```

when I try to **update** (uploading the image's binary code) the database, I get this error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

and the source error is the line in **bold**:

```
conn.Open();
**int n = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();**
conn.Close();
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you indeed wish to `INSERT` data then you need to pass real values to all columns that are mark `NOT NULL` in the table definition--except autogenerated columns like "ID".

So your insert query should look in this:

```
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Portfolio (Image, Description, ImageData) VALUES(@Image, @Description, @ImageData)";
```

And the parameters:

```
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", “myImage”);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", “WhateverYouNeed”);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageData", image);
```

**OR FOR UPDATE**
If you want to update an existing value you will need an identifier to locate the row and field you wish to `UPDATE`. In this case, you would need the "ID" of the image you wish to update.

```
comm.CommandText = “UPDATE [Portfolio] SET [ImageData] = @Image WHERE [ID] = @ID”;
```

And the parameters:

```
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", “myImage”);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(“@ID”, 123); // or whatever the ID
```

Comment: I tried setting them all to `NULL` now, and I still get the error

Comment: I'll try it though!

Comment: Because you can't send `NULL` to a table that does explicitly say "NOT NULL" for a column value

Comment: I changed the column value to `NULL` when I typed the first comment... regardless, I'm happy :)

Comment: I was just about to add an "update" button to my site :D I'll use that too!

Comment: one additional advice. Look into `using` block. It will manage the disposal of the objects that need to be disposed. Eg. SqlConnection and SqlCommand. The way your codes is presently writing you could be leaving connections open.

Comment: I will look into `using`. I don't really understand what it does from your explanation though - as I'm new to queries and SQL

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you say you're trying to **update** when your command is an **insert**. Assuming you meant insert, you have 2 columns in your schema that are NOT NULL and therefore values for those must be passed. You're currently only passing 'image' which is 'ImageData' and can be NULL so you also need to pass in data for 'Image' and 'Description'.

Comment: I just followed a youtube tutorial tbf, it's the first time I'm trying to upload images to my DB. anyway, I see what you mean... I should make `Image` & `Description` `NULL` so that information can go through - or stop the information from going through if its `NULL`. did I get this right?

Comment: Can you try the reverse and pass in those 2 additional parameters as well?

Comment: I tried adding values to both of the inputs. I deleted the useless ImageData input(since I have a button to upload images). I filled everything with info. I added a name to the button, and in the C# behind the file, I made it so that it will send the info from the 2 text inputs and then after it will send the images. got this error: `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.`. I made sure to send information in all of the inputs... and still...

Comment: I'll see if I can replicate your issue locally. Might be in about an hour though

Comment: this is it, notice the comments:https://jsfiddle.net/rqcnu1wL/